# jQuery get element by class

Tags: jquery, class

I'm currently using a script called clamp.js to cut some text, and it currently selects it by ID. I want to use it so it selects by class. The script is like this:

```
var module = document.getElementById("clampjs");
```

How can I modify that line so it selects a certain "test" div class? thanks.

Comment: Can you show your HTML?

Comment: how are you using the variable module

Answer (score 13):

Is this supposed to be marked as jQuery or JavaScript?

jQuery:

```
var module = $("#clampjs"); // by id
var module = $(".clampjs"); // by classname
```

JavaScript:

```
var module = document.getElementById("clampjs"); // by id JS version
var module = document.getElementsByClassName("campjs"); // by class JS version
```

You might want to read up on jQuery: http://www.jquery.com if that is what you meant to do!

Comment: This is the script I'm trying to use, I just want to select the element by class instead of id... https://github.com/josephschmitt/Clamp.js

Answer (score 5):

You can use [getElementsByClassName()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.getElementsByClassName):

```
var module = document.getElementsByClassName("test")[0];
```

With jQuery, you can use [class selector](http://api.jquery.com/class-selector/):

```
var module = $('.test');
```

Comment: @PopaAndrei -- The above syntax is correct - if this isnt working, the problem is else where.

Comment: @PopaAndrei You need to make sure that the class name `test` is exist in your DOM.

Comment: @PopaAndrei, `document.getElementsByClassName` Returns an array of all child elements which have any of the given class names. So you have to use indexer like `document.getElementsByClassName("test")[0]` to get its first element

Answer (score 0):

$('.Class') to get al class element
$('#id') To get an id element